# How can I work with React in a Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I started a fresh Laravel project and re-scaffolded it to use React instead of Vue. I have another developer that will be coding the React, but I will be responsible for the Laravel/backend code. I have a few questions. Does React work within blade templates? How do routes in Laravel work if we are using react? Lastly, when I run the start artisan start command, will that also start up React?

Comment: Yes, react works with blade templates. This may answer your other questions: [Using react with laravel](https://blog.pusher.com/react-laravel-application/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have the main app page for the PHP side (blade), and you can embed the react inside a div within the blade html.  The React frontend configures the DOM virtually and then displays it within that div.  Keep the frontend separate from the Laravel backend.  PHP artisan serve will start the backend up, while you will need npm run watch for the frontend side.  Use Laravel to create the backend API in which the React frontend can make calls to the server for its data needs.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes so much sense. Thank you! React will be used for the frontend and display the dynamic data instead of using PHP, right? Also, how would react router work with Laravel routes?

Comment: Yes, and you can use Laravel routes for the API routes specifically.  The React "Router" just renders a specific react component within the main page of the app.  For instance if I am on the home page of the react app and click on a different page, it will render that component within the same blade div, just under a different url defined by react.

Comment: It's a very different approach than using pure PHP with HTML & Javascript.  The backend is purely for providing and consuming data to and from the frontend.  The data is transferred over HTTP requests and can be manipulated by binding the Laravel API routes to the controller classes/functions.

Comment: Ah, understood. So dynamic urls (e.g. posts or edit profile page) would be handled by react. Everything with the frontend is all handled by react through that one blade template?

Comment: Exactly, react is awesome and keeps the frontend completely separate from the backend processing